# OData Model Not Working

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to use `expand` option in my XML view but it's resulting no data.

[image: Screenshot No Data]

Data are coming from backend as I can see in debugging under 'Network' option but there seems to be some binding issue in XML view.

## Component.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "sem/stock_app/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("sem.stock_app.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        /**
         * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
         * @public
         * @override
         */
        init: function() {
            var url = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMATLIST_SRV_02";
            var odata = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, {
                json: true
            });
            this.setModel(odata);
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
            this.getRouter().initialize();
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        }
    });
});
```

## manifest.json

```
{
    "_version": "1.7.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "sem.stock_app",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
            "version": "1.40.12"
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "icons": {
            "icon": "",
            "favIcon": "",
            "phone": "",
            "phone@2": "",
            "tablet": "",
            "tablet@2": ""
        },
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        },
        "supportedThemes": [
            "sap_hcb",
            "sap_belize"
        ]
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "sem.stock_app.view.mat",
            "type": "XML"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "sem.stock_app.i18n.i18n"
                }
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [{
                "uri": "css/style.css"
            }]
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "sem.stock_app.view",
                "controlId": "idAppControl",
                "controlAggregation": "pages"
            },
            "routes": [{
                "name": "r1",
                "pattern": "",
                "target": "t1"
            },
                {
                    "name": "r2",
                    "pattern": "page2/{noti}",
                    "target": "t2"
                }],
            "targets": {
                "t1": {
                    "viewName": "mat",
                    "viewId": "idmat",
                    "controlAggregation": "pages",
                    "viewLevel": 1
                },
                "t2": {
                    "viewName": "table",
                    "viewId": "idtable",
                    "controlAggregation": "pages",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Root View

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    controllerName="sem.stock_app.controller.mat"
    displayBlock="true"
>
    <App id="idAppControl">
        <Page title="Material Input">
            <Label text="Material Selection"/>
            <Input id="materialInput"
                type="Text"
                width="50%"
                placeholder="Enter Material"
                showSuggestion="true"
                showValueHelp="false"
                valueHelpRequest="handleValueHelp"
                submit="onSubmit"
                suggestionItems="{/matlistSet}"
            >
                <suggestionItems>
                    <core:Item text="{Matid}"/>
                </suggestionItems>
            </Input>
            <Button text="Get Details" enabled="true" press="myPress"/>
        </Page>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

## Table View

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="sem.stock_app.controller.table"
>
    <App id="tableApp">
        <Page
            title="Table"
            showNavButton="true"
            navButtonPress="onNavBack"
        >
            <Table
                growing="true"
                items="{
                    path: 'odata>/matlistSet',
                    parameters: {
                        expand: 'NP_ON_MATID'
                    }
                }"
                itemPress="onListItemPressed"
                width="100%"
                mode="MultiSelect"
            >
                <columns>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="Material ID"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="Category"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="Material Desc"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="Plant"/>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem type="Active">
                        <Text text="{odata>NP_ON_MATID/Matid}"/>
                        <Text text="{odata>NP_ON_MATID/Category}"/>
                        <Text text="{odata>NP_ON_MATID/Matdesc}"/>
                        <Text text="{odata>NP_ON_MATID/Plant}"/>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
        </Page>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

## Table Controller

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History"
], function(Controller, History) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sem.stock_app.controller.table", {
        onInit: function() {this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("r2").attachPatternMatched(this.mynav, this);
            this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().setView("table");
        },

        mynav: function(oeve) {
            var data = oeve.getParameters().arguments.noti;
            var params = "('" + data + "')?$expand=NP_ON_MATID";
            var path = "/matlistSet" + params + "";
            this.getView().bindElement(path);
        },

        onNavBack: function(window) {
            var oHistory = History.getInstance();
            var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
            if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
                window.history.go(-1);
            } else {
                var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                oRouter.navTo("overview", {}, true);
            }
        },

    });
});
```

## metadata.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema Namespace="ZMATLIST_SRV_02" xml:lang="en" sap:schema-version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
            <EntityType Name="matlist" sap:content-version="1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Matid" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Matid" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="18" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Material" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Category" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Char20" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Matdesc" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Char" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Plant" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Plant" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Char20" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Qty" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" Precision="13" Scale="3" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Quantity" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="NP_ON_MATID" Relationship="ZMATLIST_SRV_02.MATASSOCIATION" FromRole="FromRole_MATASSOCIATION" ToRole="ToRole_MATASSOCIATION" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="matdetails" sap:content-version="1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Matid" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Matid" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="18" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Material" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Matitno" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Number" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Category" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Char20" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Matdesc" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Char" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
                <Property Name="Plant" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Plant" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <Association Name="MATASSOCIATION" sap:content-version="1">
                <End Type="ZMATLIST_SRV_02.matlist" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_MATASSOCIATION" />
                <End Type="ZMATLIST_SRV_02.matdetails" Multiplicity="*" Role="ToRole_MATASSOCIATION" />
                <ReferentialConstraint>
                    <Principal Role="FromRole_MATASSOCIATION">
                        <PropertyRef Name="Matid" />
                    </Principal>
                    <Dependent Role="ToRole_MATASSOCIATION">
                        <PropertyRef Name="Matid" />
                    </Dependent>
                </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <EntityContainer Name="ZMATLIST_SRV_02_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
                <EntitySet Name="matlistSet" EntityType="ZMATLIST_SRV_02.matlist" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:pageable="false" sap:content-version="1" />
                <EntitySet Name="matdetailsSet" EntityType="ZMATLIST_SRV_02.matdetails" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:pageable="false" sap:content-version="1" />
                <AssociationSet Name="MATASSOCIATIONSet" Association="ZMATLIST_SRV_02.MATASSOCIATION" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1">
                    <End EntitySet="matlistSet" Role="FromRole_MATASSOCIATION" />
                    <End EntitySet="matdetailsSet" Role="ToRole_MATASSOCIATION" />
                </AssociationSet>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issues to fix

### Backend

- According to your service metadata, the *foreign key* inside `matdetails` is also the only *primary key* at the same time. I.e. the `Matid`s in `matdetails` cannot be unique if one `matlist` is supposed be associated with multiple `matdetails` entities.

  → Make sure that primary keys (or them combined) are all **unique** in the entire entity set.
- According to your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV9kA.png), the response body of your entity set doesn't contain the property `"results"` which is **not** OData V2 compliant (Same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43661554/5846045). See also [difference between OData V1 and OData V2](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/issues/119)). The `"response"` property needs to be there in each collection so that UI5 can display the items correctly.

  → Make sure that the response body is **OData V2 compliant**.

### Frontend

#### Model

- There was no model name passed when calling [`setModel`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#methods/getModel).

  - → Either pass the model name according to your view: `this.setModel(odata, "odata")`
  - → Or remove the model name from everywhere. E.g.: `<Text text="{Matid}"/>`
- Also worth reading: **[Stop Using `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/03/stop-using-sap.ui.model.odata.odatamodel-aka-v1-odatamodel-its-deprecated-since-2014/)!**

#### UI

- The root view and its controller are instantiating twice. In order to avoid that, please read:

  - → [Why is my Main Controller being called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47457769/5846045)
  - → Discussion in https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1746
- The application contains `<App>` multiple times. A typical UI5 application should contain only a single *root element*. If not, you might end up having [this kind of problems](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1282).

  → Remove all the `<App>` from views except from the root view.
- Since you want to display `matdetails` entities of selected `matlist` entity in the table, binding items there with the absolute path `/matlistSet` doesn't make sense.

  → Replace ...

  > ```
  > items="{
  >   path: 'odata>/matlistSet',
  >   parameters: {
  >     expand: 'NP_ON_MATID'
  >   }
  > }
  > ```

  ... with `items="{ path: 'odata>NP_ON_MATID', templateShareable: false }"`. This binding is now *relative*. The navigation property `NP_ON_MATID` will be resolved once the selected context is given in the controller. See also [Binding Path](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/2888af49635949eca14fa326d04833b9) from the documentation.

#### Controller

- On `patternMatched`, the selected `Matid` value is given. So far so good but there are two **anti-patterns** in the following lines:

  > ```js
  > var params = "('" + data + "')?$expand=NP_ON_MATID";
  > var path = "/matlistSet" + params + "";
  > ```

  1. → [Avoid creating entity key(s) manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016070/5846045).
  2. → Avoid appending `?$expand` manually as it won't expand the entity. Pass the navigation property to the `parameters/expand` of [`bindElement`/`bindObject`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Element#methods/bindElement) instead.
- Off-topic but if you want to navigate back: Remove `window` parameter from `onNavBack: function(window) { ... }`. Otherwise, the `window` in `window.history.go` is not the global `window` object but the `press` event from the back button.

Comment: I tried removing model name everywhere in view but still getting no data.

Comment: @Ajay Ok, so instead of removing, does `this.setModel(odata, "odata")` help? Otherwise, do you get any error messages in the console? Are you sure that `NP_ON_MATID` is the right navigation property of `matlistSet`?

Comment: Hi,
I tried do like this  this.setModel(odata, "odata") but it is not working.Actually i am navigating to the above view from a view which contain Inputsuggested field.But after changing the model as you told above, now no input suggestion itself is getting displayed in my view. Yes..NP_ON_MATID is the correct navigation property,because in SEGW i can run using NP_ON_MATID and getting the correct  data.

Comment: @Ajay If you've passed the model name like this `this.setModel(odata, "odata")`, kept the model name in the view like this `<Text text="{odata>NP_ON_MATID/Matid}"/>`, checked that retrieving data via `.../matlistSet?$expand=NP_ON_MATID` works in GW, and the data **still doesn't show up in the UI** without any error message, then something else is wrong. I need more context of your application. I don't know anything about your Input suggestion

Comment: @Ajay Thanks for adding the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV9kA.png). Looks like this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43661554/5846045. The result of `matlistSet` is missing the parameter `results`.

Comment: @boghyon...Thanks for your quick response.I went through the link you provided,but not able to understand how to add the 'results' in matlistSet . Can you please help.

Comment: @Ajay That's another question which you should ask separately. But even then, I'm afraid I can't help you further since I don't have any expertise in backend. Something is misconfigured there, or wrong code, or whatever..

Comment: @Boghyon..I have attached to my post one screenshot which shows that the data from backend odata are coming perfect. Please have a look for reference. Please let me know if there is any further input to this issue.

Comment: @Ajay thanks, can you please add a screenshot showing the results in JSON format? Just trying to make sure that it contains the `"results"` property for the collection.

Comment: @Boghyon...I have added one more screenshot showing odata in json format for your reference. Please let me know any input  you have to fix this issue.

Comment: @Ajay So [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV9kA.png) (let's call *s1*) contradicts with the [recent screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AMWq.png) (*s2*). The *s1* should contain the `"results"` property as well if the GW sends the data with `"results"`. But it doesn't.

Comment: @Ajay Here, I took my own screenshot from Northwind: https://i.imgur.com/kS7fAK3.gif. It contains the `"results"` property. Contrarily, the [entity set](http://services.odata.org/V2/(S(readwrite))/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json) I mentioned in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43661554/5846045) does not have the `"results"` property which was the reason for data being not displayed.

Comment: @Boghyon...Thanks for your response. Since "results" property is coming perfectly from backend which we saw in the screenshot i send. So i think issue is there in the code in UI5. Can you please let me know if any changes needs to be done in the UI5 code.

Comment: @Ajay Yes, the backend sends the request perfectly with `"results"` property but the client receives it without `"results"` according to [*s1*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV9kA.png). I don't think it's because you're using the [deprecated ODataModel](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel) but you could  try to replace it with [v2.ODataModel](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel). Be aware that batch requests and some other settings are enabled by default in v2 model.

Comment: @Boghyon..My odata runs on sap netweaver 7.51. So i don't think issue is with Odata Model. One more thing if you see last screenshot in the above attached post NP_ON_MATID comes with "results" parameter. So if there is an issue in OdataModel it won't have comes right. Please suggest your input to help fixing this issue.

Comment: @Ajay Yes, the `NP_ON_MATID` has the `"results"` but the `matlistSet` doesn't if it's expanded (as you could see in [*s1*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV9kA.png)). Please, try to read `matlistSet` with `?$expand=NP_ON_MATID&$format=json` from your GW and check if the `"results"` property is included in the response body of `matlistSet` as well - Not only in `NP_ON_MATID`.

Comment: @Boghyon..I have added the screenshot for your reference in my post. It is coming perfect in backend with "result" parameter.

Comment: @Ajay Thanks. So the question is where did the `"results"` property in `matlistSet` body go? I'm running out of ideas. Maybe if you post the rest of your code related to the model, I or someone else might be able to figure it out.

Comment: @Boghyon...I have added few more code snippet for reference. Please check and let me know if you can find any improvement for this issue.

Comment: @Ajay I updated my answer above. Thank you for the insights by providing more code. The main issue about the data being not displayed might be resolved when you **don't** call `mynav` as it's unnecessary.